# Каким образом можно реализовать звуковые эффекты на C#?

Tags: c#, аудио

Здравствуйте, подскажите в какую сторону копать по поводу реализации звуковых эффектов для простенького плеера? Я создал что-то вроде:

```
int sizeOffile = (int)file.Length; //получаем длину файла
FileStream st1 = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
byte[] memblock = new byte[sizeOffile];
st1.Read(memblock, 0, sizeOffile);
st1.Close();
MemoryStream memSt = new MemoryStream(memblock);
SoundPlayer snd1 = new SoundPlayer(memSt);
snd1.Play();
```

Каким образом на данные внутри memblock можно наложить эффекты вроде реверберации или овердрайва? В какую сторону искать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала потребуется понимание дискретной природы записи звука и его обработки. Вы можете считать файл в плеер целиком, но применять эффекты придется "побайтово", на каждый семпл дорожки. Если исходный трек - мп3 или другой пожатый формат, то сначала его придется распаковать в обычный аудио-поток, а потом, итерируя эти самые семплы, прогонять их через функцию-эффект.
Настоятельно не рекомендую с пылу с жару лезть в реверберацию, потому что вы вряд ли понимаете, насколько это сложный процесс даже для простенькой эмуляции. Вам сначала придется разработать минимально жручую линию задержки, а потом многократно применять ее с миллиардом различных параметров.
Что до овердрайва - то самая простая обработка будет простым лимитированием: каждый семпл поднимается по громкости на N дБ (шкалы децибел и паскалей - тоже отдельное веселье), а затем все сэмплы выше (громче) этого порога принимают значение самого порога (т.е. верхушка просто "срезается"). Отдельно отмечу, что волна принимает как положительные, так и отрицательные значения, поэтому порогов на самом деле два (как и диодов в простенькой схеме). Ну и в реальности у нас будут нелинейные приборы, т.е. там надо расчитывать инерцию и уменьшение сигнала по мере приближения к порогу (а если комбик эмулировать - то вам передают привет динамик и микрофон, а это эмуляция АЧХ и переходных искажений микрофона, расчет параметров Смолла-Тилля, хотя это, конечно, не для плеера), короче, пока что простого лимитирования вам за глаза хватит.
Если у вас еще не отпало желание, скачайте триал [FlowStone](http://www.dsprobotics.com/download.php) (ранее - Synthmaker), посмотрите как там модуль code организован и как на его основе дела.ются простенькие задержки.

upd. Посмотрите интерфейс VST - на самом деле это обычные dll'ки, наверняка их можно подцепить и заставить работать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Можете поподробнее объяснить каким образом производиться перегонка из байт в аудио поток? А и входные файлы формата .wav.

Comment: @MartinSeptim честное слово, не знаю. Я только теоретическую часть рассказал.

Comment: @Fike спасибо за теорию. В своих целях попытаюсь использовать библиотеку NAudio.